# Why does Entity Class return an empty value sometimes?

Tags: list-manipulation, geography, entity, natural-language

I am working on computing the 20 largest cities in California.

[image]

```
EntityList[
 EntityClass["City", 
  List[Rule[EntityProperty["City", "AdministrativeDivision"], 
    Entity["AdministrativeDivision", 
     List["California", "UnitedStates"]]], 
   Rule[EntityProperty["City", "Population"], TakeLargest[20]]]]]
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrong here.
Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: No specific answer here. Tried a few things. But here's an alternate solution (suggested by W|A queried for "cities in California"): `GeoEntities[Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}], "City"]`

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong here, I think this might be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

```
citiesCalifornia = 
  GeoEntities[
   Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}], 
   "City"];

abc = EntityList[
   SortedEntityClass[citiesCalifornia, 
    "Population" -> "Descending"]][[1 ;; 20]]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

After the comment by OP: I ran the same procedure on cities in Texas which on my machine [Win7/x64/8Gb/rot HD/ (old machine) Mma 12.2.0] took 85.4s for the first time the entities were being read. The second time around it took a few seconds.

[image]

Comment: GeoEntities takes a long to run. Absolute Timing for Texas which I'm also interested in returned 124.7 seconds. That is too long for one state if I am going to run my program over all 50 states. Maybe I could select only the cities in the UnitedStates and run the program on those?

Comment: If it runs slowly the first time, we can conclude or surmise that it is busy retrieving data. If it runs slowly the second time, then I wouldn't know how to explain it.